# Cypress OPENSSL_internal:NO_START_LINE

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

Anyone know this error? Already did cypress cache clear then reinstall it again but still getting this error. couldn't find any solution to fix this issue. I'm using version 6.5.0

`Error: error:0900006e:PEM routines:OPENSSL_internal:NO_START_LINE`

```
{
  library: 'PEM routines',
  function: 'OPENSSL_internal',
  reason: 'NO_START_LINE',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE'
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little more information around this like when are you getting this error, where are you getting this error, and what is the command you are running?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue running cypress on OSX. In my case the fix was as follows:

1. Navigate into the directory cypress stores it's proxy certificates. In my case this folder was located here:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Cypress/cy/production/proxy/
```

2. Within this folder, there is `certs` and `keys`, both have files with a list of domains accessed during cypress tests. In my case the final two files in each folder were empty:

```
~#: ls -lah key
total 240
...
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff     0B  6 May 16:40 www.google-analytics.com.key
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff     0B  6 May 16:40 www.google-analytics.com.public.key

~#: ls -lah certs
total 120
...
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff     0B  6 May 13:27 www.google-analytics.com.pem
-rw-r--r--   1 sam  staff     0B  6 May 13:27 www.googletagmanager.com.pem
```

3. I'm not sure why these `.pem` and `.key` files were empty for a handful of domains, but deleting them and rerunning a cypress test successfully regenerated them as non-empty and the tests started to pass.